# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_ball' C++, MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have beloved error C2146. I checked for possible errors and I'm unable to find one( as far as I can see there are all needed ; and after rightclick on Ball->GoToDefinition it correctly shows class declaration)

**BallMasterDoc.h**

```
#pragma once
class CBallMasterDoc : public CDocument
{
private:
    Ball m_ball; //syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_ball'
    Pod m_pod; //syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_pod'
```

**BallMasterDoc.cpp**

```
#include "Pod.h"
#include "Ball.h"
#include "BallMasterDoc.h"
```

**Ball.h**

```
#pragma once

const COLORREF BLUE = RGB(0, 0, 255);
extern int g_iRadius, g_iHeight;
extern int g_iWidth, g_iMaxWidth;//pod...

class Ball
{
public:
    Ball();
    ~Ball();
    BOOL Move(CPoint podPosition);
    BOOL Start(){ return m_bStart; }
    BOOL Collision(){ return m_bCollision; }
    BOOL End(){ return m_bEnd; }
    CRect GetArea();
private:
    BOOL CheckCollision(CPoint podPosition);
    float m_fDirection;
    int m_iB; // y = ax + B
    BOOL m_bUpDown;//true - up
    BOOL m_bStart;
    BOOL m_bCollision;
    BOOL m_bEnd;
    CPoint m_ballCentre;
    CPoint m_collisionPoint;
};
```

**Pod.h**

```
#pragma once
const COLORREF BLACK = RGB(0, 0, 0);
extern int g_iWidth, g_iMaxWidth;
class Pod
{
public:
    Pod();
    ~Pod();
    BOOL MoveLeft();
    BOOL MoveRight();
    CPoint Position() { return m_Middle; }
private:
    CPoint m_Middle;
};
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

**EDIT**

All includes are in cpp files(those generated by wizard and mine) I show just these 3 cause rest is imo uninvolved in this case. I'm learning MFC from magic book called: Microsoft Visual C++ Windows Applications by Example and there all includes go to cpp files(even if I feel its strange and book is far from best wizard supports this style...)

Comment: is Ball.h included in BallMasterDoc.h?

Comment: If you take out the various `#pragma once` lines does it make any difference?

Comment: @clcto: Doesn't the compiler need to know what a Ball is when it enters BallMasterDoc.h?

Comment: This is the reason why many style docs states a specific order to #include.

Comment: You are not using precompiled  headers !???

Comment: @JonathanPotter removing #pragma makes no difference.

Comment: @DieterLücking eee??? all includes are in cpp files(those generated by wizard and mine) I show just these 3 cause rest is imo uninvolved in this case

Comment: `BallMasterDoc.h` should include `Ball.h` and `Pod.h` because it needs those files.  (If the code you've posted is the only code in question then it shouldn't make a difference, but perhaps the errors are actually coming from some other unit which includes BallMasterDoc.h but did not include those other headers).

Comment: Which ".cpp" file is being compiled when this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `BallMasterDoc.h` depends on knowing about the `Ball` and `Pod` classes, that header file should include `Ball.h` and `Pod.h` -- instead of relying on whichever `.cpp` included BallMasterDoc.h to also include those other headers.

The `BallMasterDoc.cpp` that you posted looks OK, so your errors likely come from another `.cpp` file which does include `BallMasterDoc.h` but did not include the headers required by that header.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I put `#include"Ball.h"/"Pod.h"` in **BallMasterDoc.h** and it solved this problem but this is not satisfying answer provided code from magic book ever worked(well not this exact program and for me most of that code didn't work anyway) but it doesn't matter now

Comment: when you get the error C2146 does it tell you which `.cpp` file was being compiled when the error occurred?

Comment: If Ball.h and Pod.h were included in stdafx.h (MFC's precompiled header), it would have "magically" worked.  See if your magic book used precompiled headers and lists the code for stdafx.h with these "lower level" include files in there..

Comment: @franji1wow realy... as I have written twice(trice if we count indirect one) already all includes go to cpp files so there is NO CHANGE in stdafx.h

Comment: @MattMcNabb you're right that was error from cpp file I didn't use(modify), after I added those includes there it worked. If you want you can give answer about error coming from other unit so I accept it.